# How to get and save into db user IP using rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to save the users ip but have no idea how to make it.

My controller looks like this.

```
class CadastroController < ApplicationController
 def create
    valores = params.require(:cadastro).permit!
    cad = Cadastro.create valores
 end
end
```

my form looks like this

```
<%= form_for Cadastro.new do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <input id="nome" name="cadastro[nome]" type="text" placeholder="Nome" class="form-control input-md" required="">    
    <input id="email" name="cadastro[email]" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control input-md" required="">
    <input id="telefone" name="cadastro[telefone]" type="text" placeholder="Telefone" class="form-control input-md">
    <input id="cidade" name="cadastro[cidade]" type="text" placeholder="Cidade" class="form-control input-md">
    <button id="download" name="download" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Donwload</button>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Can someone give a hand?

Answer (score 3):

`request.remote_ip` will give you the user IP

Your `CadastroController` can look like this:

```
class CadastroController < ApplicationController
  def create
    valores = params.require(:cadastro).permit!
    cad = Cadastro.create valores.merge(user_ip: request_ip) #user_ip is the column name
  end

 private
  def request_ip
    request.remote_ip == "127.0.0.1" ? "127.0.0.1" : request.remote_ip
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm trying to save it into a string into db but the only thing it writes is "::1", do you have any guess on it?

Comment: That is an IPv6 loopback address (localhost).

Comment: @AndréSasaki. I think you are hitting request from your local. That is why you are getting a local address in ipv6 format which is `::1`

Comment: Pals apologize my ignorance, but is there any way to convert this to IPv4?

Comment: @AndréSasaki I have updated the answer. have a look!